# Is it possible to get XML coming from another domain using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to parse a XML document hosted on another domain, is this possible or does it violate the cross domain policy. I know you can `$.getScript()` from other domains, is it the same for XML? My attempts using `$.ajax()` has failed.

Comment: Of course it violates the cross domain policy.

Comment: Have you tried with a regular XmlHttpRequest? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Also, if you provide the code that you tried when using `$.ajax()`, perhaps someone can help you to fix it.

Comment: If you have control over the other domain, you can do it using a few different methods described in that other question (document.domain, JSONP, iframes, etc.). If you don't, then you'll need to build a simple proxy on your server - your browser can request from your web server, which then makes the call to the other domain and sends the result back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to overcome cross domain policy is using `JSONP`.

Answer (score 0):

The other domain will need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with url of the domain you are connecting from (e.g. `http://example.com`), or `*` to support any domain.

You can do this via a .htaccess file on Apache if you have the mod_headers module installed by adding a line like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
```

Alternatively, if you're serving up the XML via php, you could add the header with the php `header` function.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
```